# How to add css elements under a single div id all at a time?

Tags: css

#id1

#id2

.
.
.

#id500

I want to add all these ID styles applicable under a div with a id "uniform"
Do I need to add #uniform to every id styles like
#uniform #id1, #uniform #id2 etc or any other shortcuts?

I need to make this happen without manual engagement.

Comment: Could you please provide more details, as I don't understand what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [CSS `attribute^=value` selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.php). It selects all matching classes, ID's, etc. that start with a certain string. Demo:

```css
#uniform div[id^="id"] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="uniform">
  <div id="id1"></div>
  <div id="id2"></div>
  <div id="id3"></div>
  <div id="id4"></div>
  <div id="id5"></div>
  <div id="id6"></div>
</div>
```